# What is the difference between mathoverflow.net and math.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, math-se, mathoverflow

The title says it all: I'm confused as to the difference between mathoverflow.net and math.stackexchange.com.  Can anyone elaborate?

My its descriptions math.sx is a "Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields" and MathOverflow is a "Q&A for professional mathematicians".  That's not a big help... :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Math Overflow is for research-level math, so if you're a graduate student in Math or a professor, this is probably the correct site for you.

Math.SE is for Math at all levels, so any question you might ask on MO, you could also ask on Math.SE.

Comment: Shows how much I pay attention; I thought they were the same site!

Comment: If one completely overlaps the other, shouldn't something about that be changed?

Comment: The reason for the overlap is b/c Math Overflow has been around for longer.